Why is the term $H(x,y)u_{yx}$ omitted in every definition of a linear 2nd order PDE in two independent variables?
I was studying about PDEs when I came across the following definition of the general form of a second order linear PDE in $n$ independent variables:

Definition 1: The most general second-order linear partial differential equation in $n$ independent variables has the form $$\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}u_{x_i}u_{x_j}+\sum_{i=1}^nB_iu_{x_i}+Fu=G,$$ where $A_{ij},B_i, F,$ and $G$ are functions of the $n$ independent variables $x_i.$

However, then I saw that in almost everywhere a linear 2nd order pDE in two independent variables say, $x$ and $y,$ is defined as a PDE having the form $$A (x, y) u_{xx} + B (x, y) u_{xy} + C (x, y) u_{yy}
+D (x, y) u_x + E (x, y) u_y + F (x, y) u = G (x, y),$$ where $A, B, C, D, E,$ and $F$ are the coefficients, and $G$ is the nonhomogeneous term.
However, following Definition 1, I think there must be an additional term $H(x,y)u_{yx}$ in $(1)$ so that it becomes $$A (x, y) u_{xx} + B (x, y) u_{xy} + C (x, y) u_{yy}
+D (x, y) u_x + E (x, y) u_y + F (x, y) u = G (x, y),$$ where $H$ is a coefficient as well.
But why is the term $H(x,y)u_{yx}$ omitted in every definition of a linear 2nd order PDE in two independent variables?
Now, Clairaut's Theorem and all it's variants say, Schwarz's Theorem and so on require some criterias/conditions to be fulfilled in order to say that $u_{xy}=u_{yx}$ and it seems only under those circumstances we can omit that additional term $H(x,y)u_{yx}$ in equation $(1).$ But those conditions might not hold in general in case a random linear PDE is given and I think that is where the problem occurs precisely.

Clairaut's Theorem and its variants makes it so you generally are in a situation where $u_{xy}$ and $u_{yx}$ are equal, so that you only need one term to handle both of them.

But Clairaut's Theorem and all it's variants say, Schwarz's Theorem and so on require some criterias/conditions to be fulfilled in order to say $u_{xy}=u_{yx}.$ But those criterias does not have to be necessarily satisfied in case a random linear PDE is given.

@ThomasFinley, I think it's common to assume that the solutions you'd be looking for are twice-differentiable. And even if not, I wonder if there is a theorem about linear PDEs that gives you enough if the coefficients are continuous.

So, can I safely say that it is in general necessary to add the term $H(x,y)u_{yx}$ in $(1)$?

@ThomasFinley Sorry, I do not know enough about the theory of PDEs and the pedagogical traditions to confirm or deny that. Maybe there's  a theorem that says it's not necessary. Maybe it would be necessary but it's common in a presentation of linear PDEs to assume as much differentiability as the order of the equation. etc.

In principle, you are right.  But in the vast majority of cases one’s assumptions imply partials commute. So if you can’t assume it, you have to say so explicitly.

@Deane Did you intended this comment towards me? If so, then I am relieved to know that I am completely correct. So, please confirm it. Thank you!
